# setting for saving data in the list in mailchimp campaign?

Tags: mailchimp

```
** I am building a emailing techniques with mailchimp i want to store
data in the lists how can i insert data in the list of mailchimp
campaign ?**
```

is there any kind of api or something else i am new to it.
I am using laravel to do this. data store in mysql but how to start saving it in the mailchimp list ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will help you

```
 class MailChimpController extends Controller
{

    public function add( Request $request ) {
        $apikey="api key-us17";
        $server = "us17.";
        $listid = 'list id';
        if ( $request->isMethod( 'post' ) ) {
        //try {
            $request_data = $request->all();
            $email =$request_data['email'];
            $request_data['earlyprice'] = isset($request_data['earlyprice']) ? floatval($request_data['earlyprice']) : 0.0 ;
            $request->merge(['earlyprice' => $request_data['earlyprice']]);
            $request_data['gaprice'] = isset($request_data['gaprice']) ? floatval($request_data['gaprice']) : 0.0 ;
            $request->merge(['gaprice' => $request_data['gaprice']]);
            $this->validate( $request, [
                'title'       => 'required|max:255',
                'location'    => 'required|max:255',
                'starttime'   => 'required',
                'category'    => 'required',
                'type'        => 'required',
                'image'       => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048|dimensions:min_width=360,min_height=261',
                'description' => 'required|max:1000',
                'fullname'    => 'required|max:255',
                'phone'       => 'required|max:255',
                'email'       => 'required|max:255',
                'website'     => 'required',
                'socialmedia' => 'required'
            ] );

            $event     = new \App\CustomerEvent();
            $imageName = "";
            if ( $request->hasFile( 'image' ) ) {
                $imageName = md5( time() ) . '.' . $request->image->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $request->image->move( public_path( 'events_images' ), $imageName );

            }

            $requestData             = $request->all();
            $requestData['image']    = $imageName;
            $requestData['status']   = "D";
            $requestData['eventkey'] = $this->generate_key();
            $event->fill( $requestData );
            $x = $event->save();

                $auth = base64_encode( 'user:'.$apikey );
                $data = array(
                    'apikey'        => $apikey,
                    'email_address' => $email,
                    'status'        => 'subscribed',

                );
                $json_data = json_encode($data);
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'Pathto ur trigger');
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('content-type: application/json','Authorization: Basic '.$auth));
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'PHP-MCAPI/2.0');
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_data);


            //return redirect()->back()->with( 'status', 'Event created' );
        } else {
            return view( 'events.host.index' );
        }

    }
```

Comment: How can do setup for api 3.0 i mean where i can find ?

Comment: You can Find it when you creating the new campaign it is not in regular campaign.